# Error during compiling Tcl/tk

Tags: c++, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to build tcl/tk 8.5.17 for windows 7. I did build tcl successfully. However, when i try to build tk, error had occur as follow,

Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>cd C:\Program Files\Tcl\tk8.5.1
7\win
```

---

```
C:\Program Files\Tcl\tk8.5.17\win>nmake -fmakefile.vc TCLDIR=C:\Program Files\Tc
l\tcl8.5.17

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    Identifier    REG_SZ    x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10
===============================================================================
*** Compiler has 'Optimizations'
*** Compiler does not have 'Pentium 0x0f fix'
*** Linker does not have 'Win98 alignment problem'
rules.vc(522) : fatal error U1050:
Failed to find tcl.h.  The TCLDIR macro does not appear correct.
Stop.
```

---

```
C:\Program Files\Tcl\tk8.5.17\win>
```

How to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you compiled tcl but didn't install it or didn't add whatever voodoo VS needs to add tcl's include directory or -I/pathtotcl/include and if so probably the -L directory as well.  I bet it is in the build instructions.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i already install it and make file for tcl.. so what should i do?

Comment: look in C:\Program Files\Tcl\tcl8.5.17 ... should have a \include directory... otherwise you proabably need to change TCLDIR= parameter to the location that you actually installed it (probably the _other_ Program\ Files\ (x86) directory )

Comment: Might be just a missing "" around your TCLDIR value in the commandline

Answer (score 0):

make new folders as install dir for each tcl and tk. that solved my exact problem.